# Find the number and the trend?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

I was raised this question in my PSA exam and I am still not able to find the answer.The question reads::
Find the number to replace the "???" in the given box and the trend used to find it either row-wise or column-wise?? Options were::
a)2765
b)3125
c)8796
d)30008[image: Here is the BOX]>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number in the third column is $(m+n)^{(m+n)}$, where $m$ is the number in the first column and $n$ is the number in the second column..

So the answer is $(3+2)^{(3+2)} = 5^5 = 3125$.